# Difference between edx full stack and edx Ubuntu 12.04 installation

Tags: ubuntu, installation, edx

I am working with [edX](http://edx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and I've came across [a question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/edx/edx-code/Qym_u1X6PIo/60UmUImYe54J) in its google group [General Open edX discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/edx-code), which I find similar to my question.
In the group it's unanswered. I want to know,

1. What are the difference between edx full stack installation and edx ubuntu installation.
2. If I have a ubuntu 14.04 server which installation should I go for?
3. In full stack installation, why we need virtual box?

Answer (score 0):

1. The configuration of both machines almost seem the same to me. The vagrant install already has some more nice looking skins while the ubuntu one is more barebone.
2. As far as I know the ubuntu install is only verified to work on ubuntu 12.04 LTS. So the easiest way is probably the vagrant+virtualbox install.
3. You need virtualbox to use the vagrant install. Virtualbox is needed to create a virtual machine on which the server is being run. This relieves you of constraints on the operating system and you can experiment more easily without damaging your system. If you prefer an install on a clean Ubuntu installation, you need a clean 12.04 server.